# WPF 3D video memory efficiency

Tags: wpf, performance, memory, animation

Ill try to explain my situation as best as I can, sorry if it is not too clear...

I have a Viewport3D that contains some large 3d rectangles that are like big crystals.

When the user click on one of the crystals, I add a new material to the crystal in the spot the use clicked using an ImageBrush. I then iterate over a list of bitmaps (`List<BitmapImage>` collection) and update the ImageBrush each frame to create an animation on the 3D crystal.

This works nice and I have up to 5 different effects playing on the crystals, but after profiling my application, I have discovered that due to mipmaps (I think) and the way 3d renders, my video memory jumps through the roof!!

By my calculation, if I have a 75 frame animation, by 400x400 running at 4 bytes per pixel, and having ~5 different animations piled up, you can see how this can get large :)

75 * 400 * 400 * 4 * 5 = ~250MB

this is an issue, not only because of the size, but also, the BitmapImages stay in Video Memory until I make them null, which is very annoying and performance costly.

My idea to fix this is to change from having `List<BitmapImage>` collection, to having a `List<Byte[]>` and rather than updating an ImageSource, I would like to try to use a `WriteableBitmap` that write the bytes to it.

The issue is I have no idea how to read bytes from a PNG file, then create a `WriteableBitmap` and write the bytes to it over and over in an efficient manor.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: A few questions. When the user clicks on a rectangle all the crystals react or just the one clicked? The animation, does it cycle? If not do you need to keep all 75 animation frames?

Comment: Also I just googled WriteableBitmap and found this (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c4d95bf2-9b92-442b-8572-1b43bd2f2908/) thread with mentions the fact that WriteableBitmap is a memory hog and was not designed for many items/multiple updates scenarios like yours.

Comment: Firstly, just one reacts, but it is designed for multi-touch, so I am catering for many clicks at any time. Some of the 5 animations do cycle. Define "keep" all animation... Also, I have seen the exact opposite been said about the WBM, so I would perhaps like to try it out for myself :)

Comment: Looking at WriteableBitmap, I don't think it's right for you. WriteableBitmap allows you to take a WPF element and render it as a bitmap to display in an image item. You want to generate a PNG and then display that in the WriteableBitmap. To do this you need to display the PNG in an image object, and render that. So your PNG is in an image, which is rendered by the WriteableBitmap, which is then displayed in another image. Better just to display the PNG.

Comment: thanks for the advice, some of the examples that I see of the WriteableBitmap show updates to the entire WBM on each frame render, then they repaint the entire thing over and over again, and it seems to perform really well. In fact I have a small sample app that uses it very nicely... I can post it if you like? What I was going to do was simply read in bytes from the PNG as a once off thing and hold on to them, then each frame tick, write the next set of bytes onto the WBM, I dont think I need to do what you are suggesting... (but please feel free to correct me)

Answer (score 1):

WriteableBitmap is actually pretty bad with performance, even though it takes dirty regions.  Try using the InteropBitmap.  I have an class ready to go for it here:

http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/33100#809062

Comment: Hey thanks! The big questions here are, 1 will that perform at a reasonable rate, and will using a technique like this help with video memory reduction?

Comment: Also I have having trouble getting an image displayed in WPF using that class, using a byte[]... can you please provide a sample?

Comment: Try Marshal.Alloc and Marshal.Copy to allocate native memory and copy your managed byte array to your native buffer